MS Access reference files issue in CITRIX
We are using MS access in side CITRIX, However we have two references in MS Access.

comdlg32.ocx
MSINET.ocx

However these reference are not inside the CITRIX environment. I am having trouble figuring out how MS Access works having missing references.
I am using the same system in the Desktop environment and we need these references in desktop environment to work. I have checked these files are registered or not in CITRIX. These are not registered.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

First, make sure your application is deployed properly: Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment. Next: These olde OCX are 32-bit only. If you run 64-bit Access, those cannot be reached.

Well, in theory, running Access in a Citrix enviroment should not matter really much (or much the same thing as windows "terminal services", which is Microsoft's technology, and it was purchased from Citrix - hence they are both much the same in terms of how Access will run and behave for remote desktop solutions).
So while each "remote" user gets their own desktop and session?
Then on that remote server, then those two components will have to be registered. In most cases, logging on to the server (the Citrix server) as an admin, and registering the 2 components should result in those two components being "visible" or better stated "available" globally to the Access application running on that server.
So, for the most part, the Access application should not care (or even know) that it is running on Citrix. About the only exceptions I can think of if some code assumes use of files say in C:\ drive, since in theory all users are using the SAME c:\ and are all running on the one computer.  And in practice, each user that logs into the Citrix server should in theory still have their own copy of the front end file. This tends to suggest that you can't install nor use a path name to the c:\ drive for your application location, but should  then use a folder that is limited to the "one" logged on user. In most cases, I thus suggest using %appdata% for the location of the Access FE (front end).
So, those two components need to be correctly installed and registered on that Citrix server just like they are required to be installed and registered when running your application on any regular desktop. The only real difference is that a "one time" setup + install of these 2 components should suffice, and thus you not need to register the components for each logged on user. This assumes you are using "session" based logons. If you using say individual VM's for each user (not likely) then of course you need to setup + install (register) the components for each remote user you have.
Assuming you are running x32 bit Access, then you should be able to register the 2 components on that server by using regsvr32.exe. Make sure you use the x32 bit version (assuming you are running Access x32 bits). If you are running Access x64 bits, then you have to use the x64 bit version of regsvr to register the 2 components.
